# Template dual buffer class

Tags: c++, templates

I've a class that wraps 2 buffers of the same type, I need some setters and getters for these buffers and I don't want to duplicate code. I'd like to achieve this with templates but I don't know how to do it. I put some wrong code just to get the idea:

```
class DualBuffer{
 public:
  template <int idx>
  inline float<idx>* arr() {  
    // ...
  }
 private:
  float* arr0;
  float* arr1;
};

int main(){
  DualBuffer db;
  float* arr0 = db.arr<0>(); // returns a ptr to arr0
  float* arr1 = db.arr<1>(); // returns a ptr to arr1
}
```

Is this achievable? Can someone point me in the right direction with some implementation details?

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you want to use a template? Why not just an argument?

Comment: How about `std::array<float *, 2> arrs;`? Then you can `return arrs[idx];`.

Comment: @AdrianMole Looks like OP wants to access the data member by index which isn't possible. Simplest thing is to use a `std::array` or something similar.

Comment: @AnoopRana What OP wants *can* be done with a function template but it's serious overkill.

Comment: The "compile time array" would be a `std::tuple`, the corresponding subscript a `std::get<size_t>()` but I believe the `std::array` is the better choice.

Comment: @Scheff'sCat additionally, `std::array` implements the tuple interface as if it were a `std::tuple<T, T, ..., T>` so you can `std::get<idx>` it as well.

Comment: Why expose the internals of double buffer anyway? You're breaking encapsulation. You need methods on the DubbelBuffer class to access and modify data. E.g a swap method that swaps the buffer use internally. A lot of problems go away with some proper design.

Comment: *"I put some wrong code just to get the idea"*. You mostly just have "typo" in the syntax: `template <int idx> float* arr() { /*...*/ }` would be correct.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to use `std::array`. But for this particular example you can also use the method `arr` that you defined without needing it to be a function template as shown below:

```
class DualBuffer{
 public:
  //ordinary method instead of function template
  float* arr(std::size_t index) {  
    switch (index) {
      case 0: return arr0;
      case 1: return arr1;
      
      default: throw "not valid index";
    }
  
  }
 private:
  float* arr0 = nullptr;
  float* arr1 = nullptr;
};

int main(){
  DualBuffer db;
  float* arr0 = db.arr(0); // returns arr0
  float* arr1 = db.arr(1); // returns arr1
}
```